# Criando um modal com função de excluir .Net Core 2.0

Tags: .net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, modal

Boa noite, gostaria de ajuda em uma questão do .Net Core 2.0, como eu consigo criar um modal do boostrap 4 com a função de excluir no código abaixo? Meu principal problema e em como recuperar e fazer com que o botão delete do modal apague o registro da tabela.
Meu index cshtml:

```
   @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Chamados";
}

<div class="container">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h2>Lista de Chamados</b></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="~/Chamados/Cadastro" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> 
            <span>Novo Chamado</span></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                 <th>ID</th>
                 <th>Titulo</th>
                 <th>Status</th>
                 <th>Valor</th>
                 <th>Ações</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>                        
            @{
              foreach (var item in (List<ChamadosModel>)ViewBag.ListaChamados){
              <tr>          
              <td>@item.Id</td>
              <td>@item.Titulo</td>
              <td>@item.Status</td>
              <td>@item.Valor</td>
              <td>
            <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal" onclick="Editar(@item.Id)"><i class="fas fa-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"></i></a>

              <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></i></a>
              </td>
        </tr>
        }
    }
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>


    <!-- Delete Modal HTML -->
    <div id="deleteEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form>
                    <div class="modal-header">                      
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Deletar Chamado</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">                    
                        <p>Tem certeza que deseja deletar este chamado?</p>
                        <p class="text-warning"><small>Está ação não tem volta!</small></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                         @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-actions no-color">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" />                     
                    </div>
                }
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 <script>
        $(function () {

            $(".delete").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

                $("#modal").load("Delete?id=" + id, function () {
                    $("#modal").modal();
                })
            });

        })
    </script>
```

Model:

```
 public void Delete(int id)
        {
            DAL objDal = new DAL();
            string sql = $"DELETE FROM CHAMADOS WHERE ID='{id}'";

            objDal.ExecutarComandoSQL(sql);
        }
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
         public IActionResult Delete(int id){
             new ChamadosModel().Delete(id);
             return View();
         }
```

Comment: Nesse seu exemplo falta você dar o post pro servidor, não?

Comment: No meu IActionResult não estou fazendo iso? Estou começando ainda a estudar o Net Core, se não for assim poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer?

Comment: O seu controller recebe esse ajax. Voce tem q fazer ele do seu javascript pra ele.
Aqui vc pode ver a documentação de post do JQuery
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer sem utilizar ajax conforme abaixo

**View Index**

```html
<a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal" data-id="@item.Id"><i class="fas fa-trash" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></i></a>

<!-- Delete Modal HTML -->
<div id="deleteEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">            
                <div class="modal-header">                      
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Deletar Chamado</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                    
                    <p>Tem certeza que deseja deletar este chamado?</p>
                    <p class="text-warning"><small>Está ação não tem volta!</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                     
          
                <form asp-action="Delete">
                <div class="form-actions no-color">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" />                     
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basta apenas você direcionar o post do formulário para sua action "Delete" na controller.

Comment: Ele esta direcionando para o controller, porem não esta excluindo os chamados, tenho que fazer mais alguma modificação no controller ou no model que postei?

Comment: Você está dando o SaveChanges()?

Comment: Não, estou começando os estudos ainda, como eu uso no contexto da minha aplicação?

Comment: Então... em sua controller você deve:

public IActionResult(int id)
{
     new ChamadosModel.Delete(id);
     ChamadosModel.SaveChanges();

     return View();
}

Isso claro, considerando que "ChamadosModel" seja sua classe Context.